# App Script code to create documents in another Google Docs account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to write an App Script code which is supposed to look at the Gmail account of the current user under which the script is run and take the email attachments and create new documents in a separate central user account. Is it possible for app script which is running under one account to create documents in another Google Docs account?

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot directly create a file in another user's Google Drive account, you can change the owner of a document that's in the current user's account.

Refer to [File.setOwner(user)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setOwner%28String%29).